# Conditional Broadcasting in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, socket.io, pusher

Is there an easy way to conditionally broadcast when using `implement ShouldBroadcast` on events? For example:

```
/**
 * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    if ($x == 2) return;
    return ['test_channel'];
}
```

Unfortunately the code above still creates queued job, it does not succeed and continues to attempt it but cannot because it does not have a channel name. Is there an easy way to suppress the job being created with `$x == 2`?

Comment: That works, thanks, very boneheaded of me.

Comment: Glad to help! Just posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `broadcastOn` function must return an array.

So just return an empty array if you don't want to broadcast on any channels.

```
if ($x == 2) return [];
```

Comment: Tried this on Laravel7 but didn't work. Error: `Expected at least one channel`

Comment: @slayerbleast Good to know. Might be new with L7? I mean, this answer is almost four years old.

Comment: Yep, for sure they changed something to throw this exception. I only wanted to write down for future people watching this question. I solved the problem using the method `public function broadcastWhen()` like the other posted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just adding to this as Laravel now has support for a `broadcastWhen()` method on the event which covers this scenario.

e.g;

```
// on an event class...
public function broadcastWhen(){
    // check for whatever here
    return $bool;
}
```